# What's the correct pronunciation of 'Triskelion'?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, captain-america-the-winter-soldier

In *Captain America: The Winter Soldier*, S.H.I.E.L.D.'s headquarters is the Triskelion, an enormous facility in Washington D.C. I'm looking for a canon pronunciation of its name. Oddly enough, it's never said aloud during the film. I'm uncertain if it's pronounced TRIskelion or TRISkelion. I'm looking for a citation that points to something in the Marvel Cinematic Universe where we hear someone say it (I'd hope it's said at some point in *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.*).

What is the correct pronunciation of 'Triskelion'?

Comment: I remember Simmons saying it a lot, although I can't recall a specific example. She definitely pronounced it "Tri-skelion", but that may be a Briticism; I can't remember any others saying it

Comment: Are you asking for a canon pronunciation because you think it might said differently in Marvel than in "real-world" usage, or because you aren't aware [it's an actual word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triskelion) and not something Marvel made up?

Comment: @BESW Uhh, I'll go with 'both'? :3

Comment: To be fair, Simmons is British; They don't know how to pronounce anything correctly.

Comment: @phantom42 - Don't you mean prononce?

Comment: Try-skel-lee-on.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As [BESW noted in a comment on the question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/86543/whats-the-correct-pronunciation-of-triskelion#comment189455_86543), "Trikselion" is a real word. Unfortunately, it has two valid pronunciations:

So let's see if we can narrow it down in-universe.

I can't find a clip, but Simmons pronounces "Triskelion" in *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* Season 1 episode 7: "The Hub"; she pronounces it "Try-skelion":

> **Skye:** *[entering The Hub for the first time]* Wow. Didn't realize Big Brother was this big.
>
> **Simmons:** *[excitedly]* Oh, this is nothing. Wait until you see the Trikselion.
>
> <sup><sub>[*Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* Season 1 episode 7: "The Hub"](http://transcripts.foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?f=140&t=9345&sid=5e1c352ee513a23a88f6be5ed58eae15)</sub></sup>

Fitz also says it in episode 14, "T.A.H.I.T.I.". He again pronounces it "Try-skelion", but he puts more emphasis on the "-on" than Simmons does:

> **Fitz:** Buddy of mine works in the archives at the Trikselion.
>
> <sup><sub>[*Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* Season 1 episode 14: "T.A.H.I.T.I."](http://transcripts.foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?f=140&t=9977&sid=5e1c352ee513a23a88f6be5ed58eae15)</sub></sup>

However, both of these characters are of British origin. So maybe this is a cultural thing?

Fortunately, we have an American character say the name in episode 16, "End of the Beginning": Victoria Hand, and she also pronounces it "Try-skelion":

> **Hand:** Agent Sitwell. I've just received word from the Triskelion. You have orders to report to the *Lemurian Star* immediately.
>
> <sup><sub>[*Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* Season 1 episode 16: "End of the Beginning"](http://transcripts.foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?f=140&t=10549&sid=5e1c352ee513a23a88f6be5ed58eae15)</sub></sup>

Of course, astute observers will note that Hand is played by [Saffron Burrows](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0004787/?ref_=tt_cl_t8), who was born in the UK. Fortunately, Agent May is played by [Ming-Na Wen](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001840/?ref_=nv_sr_1), who is from Macau (and raised in Hong Kong). She pronounces the name later in the episode, and *still* pronounces it "Try-skelion":

> **May:** Just got a message from H.Q. Director Fury's back; he's waiting for you at the Triskelion.
>
> <sup><sub>[*Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* Season 1 episode 16: "End of the Beginning"](http://transcripts.foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?f=140&t=10549&sid=5e1c352ee513a23a88f6be5ed58eae15)</sub></sup>

Just to be extra sure, there's at least one occasion where Coulson says the name; [Clark Gregg](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0163988/?ref_=nv_sr_1) is from Boston and [Coulson](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Phil_Coulson) is from Wisconsin, so we're 100% All-American now; he says the name in episode 18, "Providence", and pronounces it the same as all the others:

> **Skye:** You were right all along: Having all this out there in the world makes it too dangerous, and now... there's no one left to protect it.
>
> **Coulson:** There's us. We were lucky enough to make it through: the Triskelion, the Hub...
>
> <sup><sub>[*Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* Season 1 episode 18: "Providence"](http://transcripts.foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?f=140&t=10970)</sub></sup>

To sum up, we're hitting the following demographics:

- [Two](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Leo_Fitz) [British](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Jemma_Simmons) characters, respectively played by a [Scottish actor](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0207691/?ref_=tt_cl_t4) and [English actress](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm4464857/?ref_=tt_cl_t5)
- An [American character](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Victoria_Hand) played by an [English actress](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0004787/?ref_=nv_sr_1)
- An [Asian-American character](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Melinda_May) played by a [Macanese actress raised in Hong Kong](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001840/?ref_=nv_sr_1)
- An [American character](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Phil_Coulson) played by an [American actor](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0163988/?ref_=nv_sr_4)

All of whom pronounce it "Try-skelion." That seems like the official pronunciation.

Comment: Marvel is virulently enforcing their copyright on this one, so I can't find any episode clips on YouTube. With the transcripts, though, it's pretty easy to find your way to the right scene quickly

Comment: 2:40 into *Melinda*, May says its again.